# Vuejs use v-if with hash variable

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use v-if with a hash variable that should be true or false.

So in jsvascript, I have

```
  data: {
    seen: {},
    bicycles: [ ...data ...],
},
```

then in created, I have the length of the bicycle array and set an item in the hash to false using the bike id as the key.

Finally,

```
methods: {
    seeMe: function (event) {
        this.seen[event.target.id]  = !this.seen[event.target.id];
        console.log("LOGGING: you pressed " + event.target.id + " and seen value is now " + this.seen[event.target.id]);
        console.log("LOGGING: the hash is now " + JSON.stringify(this.seen));
   }
}
```

In the html I have

```
        <ul>
          <li v-for="bike in bicycles">
                {{ bike.id }}
                {{ bike.make }}
                {{ bike.model }}
                {{ bike.owner.userName }} 
                <button class="button-primary" v-bind:id="bike.id" v-on:click="seeMe">{{ bike.owner.userName }}</button>
                <p><span v-if="'seen[bike.id">{{ bike.owner.firstName}} {{ bike.owner.surName}}</span></p>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

And this does not work..

Here is the console outputbefore any buttons pressed

```
LOGGING: length is 4 
LOGGING: false when i is 1 
LOGGING: false when i is 2 
LOGGING: false when i is 3
LOGGING: false when i is 4
```

and the console output after pressing button 1, button3, button 3

```
LOGGING: you pressed 1 and seen value is now true 
LOGGING: the hash is now {"1":true,"2":false,"3":false,"4":false} 
LOGGING: you pressed 3 and seen value is now true 
LOGGING: the hash is now {"1":true,"2":false,"3":true,"4":false} 
LOGGING: you pressed 3 and seen value is now false 
LOGGING: the hash is now {"1":true,"2":false,"3":false,"4":false}
```

So the hash is being updated. (There is a problem here in that it assumes that the bike records are contiguous and start at 1 and that will not necessarily be the case but that is another problem)

But the v-if is not seeing the hash and so no action is taking place when the value of seen[x] changes.

Comment: It should just be `v-if="seen[bike.owner.id]"`.

Answer (score 0):

everything that is passed to a v-if directive gets evaluated as a javascript expression, so whatever you pass to it should be valid a javascript expression.

In your case, if you do:

```
v-if="'seen['+bike.owner.id+']'"
```

This will be evaluated as a string `'seen[2]'` which is basically a truthy value (a non empty string)

What you need to do in your case is:

```
v-if="seen[bike.owner.id]"
```

Which will pass to the v-if the actual value stored in the **seen** array at the position determined by **bike.owner.id**

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you for this. Strangely it is still not working. Logging after a button press and hash entry switch is "the hash is now {"1":false,"2":false,"3":false,"4":true}" yet  v-if="seen[bike.owner.id]" (nor hard-coding "seen['3']" or "seen[3]") is not displaying the code.

Comment: @John The best way to help you would be if you provide a boiled down repo reproducing your problem so we can see what you're doing in your code and provide some guidance. Try this https://codesandbox.io/ and let me know when you do it, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The initialisation of the map in created I simply had as

this.seen = false;

I changed this to

Vue.set(this.seen, i, false);

and now it works.